# Crontab not working'

Tags: bash, python, 17.10, cron

I'm kinda new to ubuntu so ...

Well the issue is I need to use a script made in python and did one in bash ... neither worked on crontab to see how many IP addresses I have in my home network and the python script usually does it.

```
'import os


os.system("touch test.html")

os.system("nmap 192.168.0.1/24 >> test.html")

'
```

Here is the example: [image: Crontab -e photo of mine]

Still can't figure it out. So I tried this multiple times through youtube tutorials and this forum still nada.

Comment: Did you use 'crontab -e'? You may need 'sudo crontab -e'

Comment: @JohnAnderson Why should `nmap` be started as root?

Comment: I did both still nada

Comment: Are the single quotes part of your file?  If they are, remove them.  Secondly, nmap will take longer than a minute to run, so you might want to change that to every 10 or so for testing.

Comment: Another thought here, add in a location that test.html will be created like `"nmap 192.168.0.1/24 >> /home/username/test.html"`.  As it stands, it might be creating in the working folder that cron is running in.

Comment: Is your Py3 interpreter really located in your /home dir?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a permission problem with one or more of the filenames in your python program. You should fully specify the entire path to the file `test.html`

To get more information you should redirect the output to a file so you can see the error messages. Otherwise check the mail system for crontab output.

Try

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/luisgio/jobs/nmap.py > /tmp/nmap.log 2>&1
```

Also:
  Check that /usr/bin/python3 is installed on your system.
  We assume the program works from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
/home/luisgio/jobs/python3
```

is the wrong path. You probably want

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/luisgio/jobs/nmap.py
```

as you want the python interpreter to load your script.

Comment: Thank you for the help but still nada

Comment: Besides, I'd rather recommend not to run crontab every minute... And if you really want to troubleshoot it, it is highly recommended to add log of cronJob as following `/usr/bin/python3 /home/luisgio/jobs/nmap.py >> >> /var/log/yourLogFolder/nmap.log 2>&1`

Comment: Try to log it and see what is the output

Comment: Nope, still nothing

Comment: My lucky guess is that the folder that im trying to execute doesnt work due to its locations

Comment: What does that mean?